# Is it possible to upgrade my GT310M by soldering another GPU in my Sony's motherboard?

Tags: laptop, gpu, nvidia-geforce, soldering

Sorry if this is a newbie question, but I couldn't find anything concrete around the web. I have a Sony Vaio VPCF121FX and it has a motherboard soldered GPU (GT310M).
I want to know if it's possible to upgrade this GPU with a GT445M or any other that may be supported.

@: If it is possible, I'm aware that soldering things to the motherboard is something dangerous.

@: All I could find is that it's not supported because the GPU is soldered to the motherboard, but in case my GT310M stop working, I would have to solder another GT310M to replace. I know it's not something that easy, but I suppose it's not impossible to solder a GPU, or it is?

@: In case it's possible, how can I know what GPU I would be able to solder in my Sony's motherboard?

Thanks for attention and sorry for bad english (I'm brazilian and not very used with english).

Peace,
Eduardo Barth.

Comment: The type of soldering necessary puts it very firmly in the specialised service category and would require a PCB manufacturer or similar shop to do the work, it is impossible for you to reliably do this yourself. For a single unit to be reworked I would expect the time and cost of work to be prohibitive at best and exorbitant at worst. If your graphics card or processor are soldered then it will almost certainly be cheaper to buy a new laptop.

Comment: if you have an Express card slot you can try to use an adapter to use normal Desktop GPUs: http://www.notebookreview.com/default.asp?newsID=5846&review=how+to+upgrade+laptop+graphics+notebook

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. Soldering a GPU by hand with hobbyist-level hardware and experience is extremely unlikely to be successful. In addition, even if the soldiering were to succeed, the added power draw and heat would likely fall outside the operating parameters of the other laptop components such as village regulators and cooling system. If improved performance is required, you will need to look at purchasing a different laptop with better or newer hardware.

To answer one of your secondary questions, if the existing GPU (or most other motherboard components) fails, the motherboard would need to be replaced as a whole.